# Domain clients cannot UNC to \\domain. They can UNC to \\domain\netlogon and \\domain\sysvol

Tags: windows, active-directory, unc

Server 2019 domain controllers and Server 2019 member servers.
We can enter these UNC paths in File Explorer or the Run prompt:

```
\\mydomain\netvol
\\mydomain\sysvol
\\mydomain.com\netvol
\\mydomain.com\sysvol
```

However, we cannot enter these UN paths. When we do, it fails with the error "Network Path Not Found":

```
\\mydomain
\\mydomain.com
```

If we don't specify a folder under "\mydomain," the system fails to connect. We are able to UNC into our 3 domain controllers:

```
\\\\dc1
\\\\dc2
\\\\dc3
```

In our development domain, we can browse to all of those UNC paths with no issues. We're painstakingly comparing GPO's and DNS settings between the two domains, but we haven't found anything yet.

Do you have any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: What specific functionality is this causing an issue for? Domain clients only need to connect to the netlogon and sysvol shares on domain controllers.

Comment: We're setting up DFS (distributed file system) namespaces, in which shares appear under the root share. Our common network drives would be \\mydomain.com\images, \\mydomain.com\spreadsheets, and so on. If a user forgets the exact path to the DFS share they need, it's convenient for them to simply enter \\mydomain.com to see the shares available.